# set_flashdata some times not working in my codeigniter application

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter , in my controller i can not set the flashdata , but i can set the user data

```
 /**
 * this will send the requests for the gmail wrapper
 * @return void
 * @author Sandaruwan
 * */

function send_contacts()
{
    $contacts = $this->input->post('contact');
    if (count($contacts) != 0 && is_array($contacts)) 
    {   
        $data = $this->gmailmanager->send_messeges($contacts);

         echo "error message ===>"; print_r($this->message->get_message ()); echo "<br/>";

        $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$this->message->get_message ());
        echo "flash data ===>"; print_r($this->session->flashdata('message')); echo "<br/>";


        $this->session->set_userdata('user',$this->message->get_message ());
        echo "user data ===>"; print_r($this->session->userdata('user')); echo "<br/>";

        exit;

        redirect('connections/connection_inviter/invite');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->message->set_information(array(_('You have not selected a conatact!')));
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message',$this->message->get_message ());
        redirect('connections/connection_inviter/invite');  
    }
}
```

this is the result

```
    error message ===>

    Warning

        Email sending error!


    flash data ===>
    user data ===>

    Warning

        Email sending error

!
```

the problem is i can get the `error message` and `userdata`  but can not get the `flashdata` , i can not figure out why i can not get the `flashdata` right after initialized .

in some controllers flashdata works perfectly .

UPDATE

```
function invite() {
$this->load->library("connections/Outlookmanager");

print_r($this->ci->session->flashdata('message'); die;

    //Invite friends links        
$this->data['is_windows']=$this->outlookmanager->is_windows_user();
$this->load->view('connections/invite_friends', $this->data);

}
```

when i print `flashdata` in `function invite()` it is not printing .

**UPDATE**

hmmmm . actually there is a very interesting issue ,

i had the error message `Email sending error` i changed it to `err` now flash data working . i again changed message to `Email sending error` and it is again not working . then i again changed it to `err` then again flashdata works .

what is this , i think error message length is causing the problem here , and i don't know why

Comment: please tell me why are you giving me (-) . i have stuck in this whole day :(

Comment: also tried keep_flashdata but not working

Answer (score 4):

That's because flashdatas are (though CI uses the word "session"), actually, cookies, and therefore they're available only at the next request.

To be honest, I don't see the reason of setting and calling flashdatas right after their creation, why don't just print out the error instead and skip this useless step?

If you still want both, just do

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('message',$this->message->get_message());
echo $this->message->get_message();
```

So that you have a message now, and a message on whatever request you make later on

**UPDATE:**

Try calling the method of the `$this` instance instead of `$this->ci`

```
print_r($this->session->flashdata('message');
```

I think I already saw you doing like this, using sometimes the reference to `$this` and sometimes to another object, and IIRC I even answered a question about the difference. Why that? Why you use `$this` in a location and then `$this->ci->` in another?
It might not make difference, but at least for the sake of consistency stick to one way (and I suggest using the "regular" one)

Comment: ;)   actually the thing is in my redirect page redirect('connections/connection_inviter/invite');  when i try to use the flashdata it is not working . so that's why i am trying to print it right after the initialization .

Comment: Yeah but you're redirecting to _another page_ , there you'll find your flashdatas. If you're saying that your session are not printed _there_, well, your question then is not clear at all, for this problem is never addressed. So you say that in "connections/connection_inviter/invite" you don't see flashdatas?

Comment: yep . that is the case . i can not see flash data there . please see my update

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya might be that you reached the maximun lenght allowed for a cookie (usually 4Kb), but that's just a wild guess

Comment: Don't abuse the feature, use it to store small amount of datas; or use a database instead, or native php $_SESSION